# adding context variables in python logs

Tags: python, django, logging

I am developping a python application and I would like to include a very detailed stack info in case of exceptions, including all local variables. This is what is done in Django

I have set up the Python (in Python 3)  log and with logger.debug (' error in knitting ',exc_info = True, stack_info = True, extra = dicte) I get the stack trace but not the list of internal variables and their content. How can I do this?

what I would like to get is th following:

▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
args

()

kwargs

{'tech_number': 108}

name

'get'

self

Comment: Could you please give an extended example of the input/output you are expecting?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question. But I think you could put whatever you want into `extra` as a python dict. Then you need

1. overwrite your `record.message` in function `format`
2. set `format` to your `logger`

Here is part of the code as example [Link](https://github.com/NSLS-II/caproto/blob/8ac97dc5224fac5f04b6db5aa794b5a41ac7d352/caproto/_log.py#L109-L112)